# Difference between geometric transformation and substitution in integral

Tags: analysis

In my first semester of university I learned using substitution for integrals (I study physics not math). Now I took a math class where we were introduced to transformation, for example polar coordinates, etc. I already knew polar coodinates from physics but for me it seemed like just a good substitution.
Now I wonder if substitution and transformation are the same thing or not.

I appreciate an explanation.

Comment: If you integrate a function of two variables over circle in cartesian coordinates and use polar substitution, domain of integration “unrolls” into rectangle with sides on $r$ and $\varphi$ axes.